# Python parallelize, function, with one iterable and mulitple data as input. Maybe mulitprocessing starmap?

Tags: python, python-multiprocessing

I currently have the following loops, creating a matrix by by calculating each column using my function sample_features. The function takes input an index that is my iterable and multiple datasets and parameters that needs to be repeated for all function calls.

```
def sample_features(train_data, train_rating, Item_vector, mu_U, Lambda_U, i, alpha, name='User'):
        if name=='User':
            idx=(train_data[:,0]==i)
            V_j = Item_vector[:,train_data[idx,1]]
        else: 
            idx=(train_data[:,1]==i)
            V_j = Item_vector[:,train_data[idx,0]]
        
        Lambda_i_star=Lambda_U + alpha*np.dot(V_j, V_j.T)
        Lambda_i_star_inv=np.linalg.inv(Lambda_i_star)
        mu_i_star=np.dot(Lambda_i_star_inv,(alpha*np.dot(train_rating[idx],V_j.T)+np.dot(Lambda_U,mu_U)))
        return multivariate_normal(mu_i_star, Lambda_i_star_inv)

for i in range(num_User):
        U_new[:,i]=sample_features(train_data, train_rating, Item_vector, mu_U, Lambda_U, i, alpha, name='User')
            
for j in range(num_Item):
        V_new[:,j]=sample_features(train_data, train_rating, U_new, mu_V, Lambda_V, j, alpha, name='Item')
```

Dimensions:
U_new (N x D)
V_new & Item_vector (M x D)
train_data (Rx2)
train_rating (Rx1)
mu_U & mu_V (D x 1)
Lambda_U & Lambda_V (D x D)
i & j & alpha (1x1)

I am pretty new to parallelization, as I am math student, and not computer science. I researched and seemed to find that I should maybe use starmap() function from the multiprocessing package, but I couldn't get it to work properly.

Answer (score 0):

The issue here revolves around how Python handles data in multiprocessing apps.  Each Process lives in its own address space, which means that Processes cannot directly share variables with one another.  If you use a function like `multiprocessing.pool.starmap`, Python will transfer every function argument to the worker Processes using a Queue.  That entails converting the data to a binary format (with the standard pickle module) and subsequently re-constituting it as Python objects.  This may offset any performance benefit you get from multiprocessing.

In your case it looks to me like you have a rather large amount of fixed data, i.e., data objects that do not vary from one step to the next.  The only two exceptions that I see in your code are i and j.  In such situations, it's best to initialize each worker process with its own copy of the fixed arguments.  These will only have to be transferred once, at the beginning of each Process, instead of for every call.  To do this, however, requires some care.  The following little program shows a possible framework.

```
import os
import time # added in edit
import multiprocessing as mp
from types import SimpleNamespace

_vars = SimpleNamespace()

def init_fixed(arg1, arg2):
    _vars.arg1 = arg1
    _vars.arg2 = arg2
    
def func(i, name):
    time.sleep(0.5)  # added in edit
    print(os.getpid(), i, name, _vars.arg1, _vars.arg2)
    return f"{name} {i}" 
    
def main():
    with mp.Pool(initializer=init_fixed, initargs=("arg1", "arg2")) as pool:
        i_result = pool.starmap(func, ((i, "name1") for i in range(10)))
        j_result = pool.starmap(func, ((j, "name2") for j in range(20, 40)))
    print(i_result, j_result)
    
if __name__ == "__main__":
    main()
```

The Pool constructor takes keyword arguments `initializer` and `initargs`, which you use to pass a function and some arguments.  This will happen once per Process, so here is where you set the data that doesn't change.  You have to put this data somewhere, in a place that your worker function can find.  For this I have created a global `_vars`, a SimpleNamespace, on which you can set any attributes you want.

The worker function, `func`, can now access this data as members of `_vars`.  I am showing a case where there are two variables passed to each worker function using the `starmap` function.  Within `func`, you can access both the initialization data and also the arguments.  I am also printing out the operating system's Process ID so you can see how the work is distributed among the different Processes.

I am not sure if I understand your requirements enough to take this further.  From the arguments in your code, You may need to create two pools with different initializers, but I am not sure about that.

Even though the code looks as if there is only *one* object named `_vars`, at runtime each Process will in fact have its own set of global variables.  Each Process actually has its own unique copy of `_vars`, and each Process knows nothing about the copies that live in other Processes.  All the `_vars` objects are initialized with the same data, so it works.

Comment: When I try to run your code, I get the same Process ID all through. The whole point for it is to get it to run my calculations in parallel to save time. I understand the part of only passing my data to a worker once, and do 1/4 of the calculations (if I have 4 workers), instead of passing all the data everytime one calculations has to be done. But I am not sure how your code does that?

Comment: When I run my code I do NOT get the same process ID throughout.  However, the first few iterations of func run in the same process, presumably because the other processes have not started yet.  Try putting a short time delay (time.sleep) in func - perhaps your computer is faster than mine.  I tried to explain that my code passes all the fixed arguments once, through the initialize function which gets called once per process initialization. That data is stores in a namespace for later retrieval and each call to func passes only the arguments that change.

Comment: I modified the script to include a time delay.  On my machine, 4 func calls execute in parallel in 4 different processes, every time.